# python insert live textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a series of commands that needs to be executed.  After each execution, I'm printing out "Uploading...blah blah blah", or "Failed".

In the terminal, I can see that after each execution, the status is immediately printed out.

[1]

Using tkinter, I'm trying to output the same status in a text box.  Same thing, after each execution, I would like to see my status.  However in this text box, the status is printed out all at once at the end of the script (Like in my example, I don't see "Uploading splash screen" until everything is done.)

```
def actions():
# Enable VNC
    if action_VNC.get():
        print("Enabling VNC...")
        msg_initVNC = "Enabling VNC..." + "\n"
        outText.insert(tk.END, msg_initVNC)

#DO STUFF HERE
        print('Success. VNC enabled.')
        print('########')
        msg_outVNC = 'Success.  VNC enabled.' + "\n" + '########' +"\n"
        outText.insert(tk.END, msg_outVNC)
```

Here my my text box code:

```
outText = Text(window, width=50, height=20, wrap=WORD)
outText.grid(row=8, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
```

I've also tried this:

```
        label1 = Label(text= "Enabling VNC..." + '\n', font=("Arial", 14), anchor=CENTER)
    label1.grid (column=0, row = 9, columnspan=3, pady=10)
```

in place of the outText.  I get the same results

Comment: Use `Label(text=...)` and `pack()` the label onto the screen or a frame, make sure to define new label each time for each status, if your looking for an answer, you might need to give some code here

Comment: I just updated my question with some sample code.  The entire code is quite long.  But the attached piece exhibits the same problem.  I'll give the label(text=...) a try.  Thanks.

Comment: Im sorry but the code has to be something that we can copy and paste and try and not an image.

Comment: Sorry....I'm new here.  Code is updated.  The #Do Stuff Here part is the actions.  It takes about 1-2 seconds to execute but it works.  I'd like to see "Enabling VNC..." wait 1-2 seconds followed by "success...blah blah".   Right now, it just blurts everything at the end.

Comment: What is `outText` ?

Comment: outText is my text box.  It's defined later below in the code (not shown)....Ooooo...could it be because outText is defined 300 lines below?  Give me a sec...I'll update my post

Comment: Use a `Label` rather than a `Text` ?

Comment: I just tried that.  It does the same thing.  Both text outputs at the same time.  :(

Comment: Try `window.after(1000,lambda:Label(text= "Enabling VNC..." + '\n', font=("Arial", 14), anchor=CENTER).grid(column=0, row = 9, columnspan=3, pady=10))` You could use `time.sleep(1)` but it will freeze the GUI, other than that i dont think there is a way to do so